# How the centralized server model is updated with aggregated client metrics in TensorflowFederated

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I have designed the Federated Learning model with TensorFlow Federated framework. Defined the iterative process as below,

```
iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
    model_fn,
    client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.0),
    server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.9))
```

I have 2 remote workers running the tffruntime remote executor service and the context for running computation is defined as `tff.backends.native.set_remote_python_execution_context(channels)`. When the model is broadcasted to the client with `iterative_process.next(state, train_data)`, how can we identify that the client metrics is aggregated and applied to the server model. Is the single api `build_federated_averaging_process` is enough to get the metrics from clients, aggregate and then update the server model? If means how can we identify that the server model is updated? Can anyone please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

The `build_federated_averaging_process` API builds an iterative process of the full federated learning steps. If you want to verify that the server model is updated, you can print `state.model` after each `iterative_process.next(state, train_data)`.

Comment: ````NUM_ROUNDS = 20
    for round_num in range(0, NUM_ROUNDS): 
    state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, train_data) 
    print(server.model)````
I am getting error as ‘server’ is not defined.Is this the right way to check the server model? Or can we check only the wights assigned to the model as ````state.model````

Comment: Yeah, it should be `state.model`, sorry about the typo.